# unable to bind event on dynamic object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have to bind an event which triggers on click of any option inside a list.The list is the auto suggest list which is dynamic.it comes when some types something on suggester.

I have to bind an event on click of the element of list for GA tracking.

this is the html before list come.

```
<div class="head-auto-search-col header-autosearch-result-div" id="header-autosearch-result-div">

                </div>
```

once the list comes it becomes.

```
<div class="head-auto-search-col header-autosearch-result-div" id="header-autosearch-result-div">
<ul class="head-auto-search">
<li href="http://bangalore.quikr.com/astrology-astrology-numerology/astrology/x236" class="first-li"><span class="head-auto-sugg-span1"><b>astrology</b></span><span class="head-auto-sugg-span2">in Astrology - Numerology</span></li>

<li href="http://bangalore.quikr.com/astrologer-astrology-numerology/astrologer/x236"><span class="head-auto-sugg-span1"><b>astrologer</b></span><span class="head-auto-sugg-span2">in Astrology - Numerology</span></li>

<!--More li -->
</ul>
</div>
```

The js code i have written for that is

```
$(document).on("click",".head-auto-search li",function(){
  var category='Header_Responsive';
  var action='gaPageAction';
  var label='click_autosearch_list';
  getEventTrackGA({'category':category,'action':action,'label':label}); //function call for ga tracking. 
});
```

this funtion doesn't work.I dont know what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.head-auto-search-col').on("click",".head-auto-search li",function(){
  var category='Header_Responsive';
  var action='gaPageAction';
  var label='click_autosearch_list';
  getEventTrackGA({'category':category,'action':action,'label':label}); //function call for ga tracking. 
});
```

This binds the listener to the static element on your page, which should allow the listener to hear events from the dynamically created list elements.

Comment: it works could you please explains what is the problem with previous statement?

Comment: I think the problem with the previous statement is that it isn't wrapped in a `$(document).ready` check. Thus, the listener is not properly attaching to the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

If `<div class="head-auto-search-col header-autosearch-result-div" id="header-autosearch-result-div">` was there after page rendering without dynamic created, then this below code look fine:

```
$('#header-autosearch-result-div').on("click",".head-auto-search li",function(){ });
```